# Elastic Search Load Testing

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single node elastic search server running on ec2. I want to do some load testing using search requests with random search queries. I am using JMeter for load testing with two different approaches -

1. HTTP Client - When I test using these clients with 10k/20k/50k of requests, it works fine.
2. ES Transport Client - This works fine with approx 2k of requests.

Here are the steps I have followed -

1. Instantiating client on every run and close it once the test finished.
2. Once client instantiates, I start the jmeter sampling and send the search request.
3. After this run, stops the sampling.

I am getting **No Node Available Exception** after 2k of request with transport client.

ES Server is running with 3g of memory and have given 6g of memory to load tester.

Please help me if there is some config modification required and if I am not using the correct approach to test the load.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you show a full strack trace of the exception?

Comment: So, By Es transport client, do you mean Java? And Are you sure it is es error (not java). ? Maybe java heap memory is low..

Answer (score 0):

What kind of responses are you getting from the http test? Have you verified you are getting valid responses for all 10~50k requests? It might be perhaps your cluster cannot take on the load you're putting on it for either test. Since TransportClient is more intimately coupled to the ES server, you will explicitly see errors that come back from TransportClient, but if you're simply sending requests via HTTP without validating the response, it's easy to miss any issues.

Although, before taking a stab in the dark like I just did, I would also check to see what kind of QPS you are getting using the HTTP method vs the TC method, what your CPU/memory look like throughout both tests, what the response times look like, etc. It helps to monitor the health of your system throughout the process to detect any symptoms that might help explain the cause.